# Is it possible to set page layout for an SSRS report using report parameters?

Tags: layout, reporting-services, printing, reporting

I'm using SSRS to generate reports in my app.  My app calls the web service behind the scenes.  In some cases I render the report using the ReportViewer web control, in other cases (if user is using Webkit based browser for example), I just allow them to download a pdf of the report.  I set the report parameters programatically.

How can I give my users the ability to decide on the layout of the page (margins, landscape/portrait, paper size)?  Is there someway to configure the report layout using report params?

The ability to choose between Letter and Legal is my main interest.

Alternative is to build 2 version of each report but I hate repetition.

Comment: Why cant they make these types of choices in the PDF themselves?

Comment: If the pdf was rendered to 8.5x11, your pdf viewer can't change the height/width ratio of each page.  All it can do is crop or enlarge.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if your are using the ReportViewer here's how to do it:

```
reportViewer.SetPageSettings(new PageSettings()
{
  Landscape = false,
  Margins = new Margins()
  {
    Left = 1,
    Top = 1,
    Right = 1,
    Bottom = 1,
  },
  PaperSize = new PaperSize()
  {
    Height = 1100,
    Width = 850,
    RawKind = (int)PaperKind.Letter,
  }
});
```

Hope this helps..